# Unable to get User's data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

This is probably something really stupid on my end, but I'll ask anyway:

Suppose I have a column in my User table called 'test'. This field contains a string.

Why does this code log 'undefined' in the console? What am I doing wrong?

```
//User is logged on successfully
var user = Parse.User.current();
console.log(user.get("test"));
```

I'm confused. `user.get("username")` and `user.get("id")` work just fine. I know that `user.getUsername()` exists, but I used the former just for testing.

If I can use `user.get("username")`, why I can't I use `user.get("other-column-name")`?

[EDIT] Thanks to nemesv, my code almost works. However, there is ONE catch.

If I change data in the data browser, the first time I refresh my app, it shows the old data. However, on subsequent refreshes, the data is corrected. Is there a solution?

Comment: You can try to call fetch before calling get: `var user = Parse.User.current(); user.on('change', function() {console.log(user.get("test"));}); user.fetch(); //async`

Comment: Your solution almost works. Please see my edit.

Comment: I think you should also put the code in question where you are changing the data. It may help others in answering the question.

Comment: I'm changing the data via the Data Browser, not via the SDK.