# Parse.com: user is not defined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com as a back end for a web app. I have a user that I have signed in to the app, and when the user is signed in to the website, I want their name to appear on every page in the website.

Here is my code for trying to recognize the username of the user:

```
// user logs on and is redirected to this page
var user = Parse.User.current();
user.on('change', function () {
console.log(user.get("username"));
});
user.fetch();
```

However, when I check the console, the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined
```

is present.

In my research, I've modified the code from [Unable to get User's data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896870/unable-to-get-users-data). However, in my case, this code is not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
user.fetch().then(function(fetchedUser){
    var name = fetchedUser.getUsername();
}, function(error){
    //Handle the error
});
```